# Cannot find template twig path

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a question regarding how can I specify correctly the twig template inside a function in php? I have the following structure:

```
src
  User
     EmailBundle
           DependencyInjection
           Resources
                views
                    Default
                        email-base.html.twig
           Services
```

And what I am trying:

```
$template = $this->emailService->getTemplate(
        'UserEmailBundle:Default/email-base.html.twig'
)
```

And is not working, it displays the error that cannot find the template. What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your bundle is EmailBundle and not UserEmailBundle, so try changing:
`UserEmailBundle:Default/email-base.html.twig` to  `EmailBundle:Default/email-base.html.twig`

looking at this question again, maybe I am wrong, did you try:

`UserEmailBundle:Default:email-base.html.twig` ?

Answer (score 1):

`@Email/Default/email-base.html.twig` works, or alternatively `EmailBundle:Default:email-base.html.twig`.

Assuming this setup:

```
src
    User
        EmailBundle
            EmailBundle.php
            Resources
                views
                    Default
                        email-base.html.twig
```

Check your composer.json, it should look like this:

```
// ...

"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle", "User\\": "src/User"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},

// ...
```

Also confirm that you have registered your bundle in AppKernel.php:

```
// ...
$bundles = [
    // ...
    new \User\EmailBundle\EmailBundle(),
    new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
];
// ...
```

Comment: I thought too that it is EmailBundle.php, but then I remembered that sonata uses that kind of namespacing and bundle name is UserEmailBundle.php

Comment: @kunicmarko20 Hmm I just tested it by recreating the project, and it worked just fine.

Comment: I was talking about the Bundle name, as we do not have any info it can be `UserEmailBundle` but it can also be `EmailBundle`

Comment: @kunicmarko20 Ah I'm sorry. The OP should clarify that.